# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor returned when write file to a new python environment

Tags: python-3.x

I tried searching through how to fix this problem but still not able to resolve this...

I have created a python environment using anaconda prompt. I activated that environment and ran below code:

```
import os

os.makedirs(os.path.join('..', 'data'), exist_ok=True)
data_file = os.path.join('..', 'data', 'house_tiny.csv')
with open(data_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write('NumRooms,Alley,Price\n')  # Column names
    f.write('NA,Pave,127500\n')  # Each row represents a data example
    f.write('2,NA,106000\n')
    f.write('4,NA,178100\n')
    f.write('NA,NA,140000\n')
```

It then returned the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\CATHYS~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1944/3610714214.py in <module>
      8     f.write('2,NA,106000\n')
      9     f.write('4,NA,178100\n')
---> 10     f.write('NA,NA,140000\n')

OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: are you running this in IPython or Jupyter or something? the path looks odd.

Comment: to get around that path issue, maybe try just specifying the direct path instead of relying on `..`

Comment: Your code works for me when I run it in an interactive shell but as the others have said, better provide an absolute file path and make sure that you have write access in that location.

Comment: I did that on Jupiter. I just changed the and it works now. Many thanks!